# CUBE + outer join = extra NULL row

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join, cube, rolap

When I use PostgreSQL's [CUBE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) on a query with an OUTER JOIN, I get an extra all-NULL row that can't be distinguished from the cube's own "everything combined" all-NULL result.

```
CREATE TABLE species
  ( id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name  TEXT);

CREATE TABLE pet
  ( species_id INTEGER REFERENCES species(id),
    is_adult   BOOLEAN, 
    number     INTEGER)
;

INSERT INTO species VALUES
  (1, 'cat'), (2, 'dog');

INSERT INTO pet VALUES
  (1, true, 3), (1, false, 1), (2, true, 1), (null, true, 2);
```

OK, so there are 7 pets total:

```
SELECT SUM(number) FROM pet;
 sum
-----
   7
(1 row)
```

Now look at the total row of the cube:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT name, is_adult, SUM(number)
        FROM   pet p
        JOIN   species s ON (p.species_id = s.id)
        GROUP BY CUBE (name, is_adult)) subq
WHERE name IS NULL
AND   is_adult IS NULL;

 name | is_adult | sum
------+----------+-----
      |          |   5
(1 row)
```

5 pets?  Oh, right, because the no-species pets aren't being included.  I need an outer join.

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT name, is_adult, SUM(number)
        FROM   pet p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN   species s ON (p.species_id = s.id)
        GROUP BY CUBE (name, is_adult)) subq
WHERE name IS NULL
AND   is_adult IS NULL;

 name | is_adult | sum 
------+----------+-----
      |          |   2
      |          |   7
(2 rows)
```

My cube has 2 all-null rows; the second one is the answer I wanted.

I half-understand what is going on here: NULL values are used to signal two different things ("the cube has rolled up all this column's values" or "this row has no children in the right-side table").  I just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> NULL values are used to signal two different things ("the cube has
>   rolled up all this column's values" or "this row has no children in
>   the right-side table").

In order to distinguish one null from the other null, you can use `grouping(...)` function, see table 9-55 here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-GROUPING-TABLE

> **GROUPING(args...)** Integer bit mask indicating which arguments
>   are not being included in the current grouping set
>  Grouping
>   operations are used in conjunction with grouping sets (see Section
>   7.2.4) to distinguish result rows. The arguments to the GROUPING operation are not actually evaluated, but they must match exactly
>   expressions given in the GROUP BY clause of the associated query
>   level. Bits are assigned with the rightmost argument being the
>   least-significant bit; each bit is 0 if the corresponding expression
>   is included in the grouping criteria of the grouping set generating
>   the result row, and 1 if it is not.

---

> ```
>  name | is_adult | sum 
> ------+----------+-----
>       |          |   2
>       |          |   7
> ```
>
> the second one is the answer I wanted.

Try this:

```
SELECT name, is_adult, SUM(number)
FROM   pet p
LEFT OUTER JOIN   species s ON (p.species_id = s.id)
GROUP BY CUBE (name, is_adult)
HAVING grouping(name,is_adult) = 3

name |is_adult |sum  |
-----|---------|-----|
     |         |7    |
```

---

Please also examine this query to learn how `grouping` function works:

```
SELECT name, is_adult, SUM(number), grouping(name,is_adult)
FROM   pet p
LEFT OUTER JOIN   species s ON (p.species_id = s.id)
GROUP BY CUBE (name, is_adult)

name |is_adult |sum |grouping |
-----|---------|----|---------|
cat  |false    |1   |0        |
cat  |true     |3   |0        |
cat  |         |4   |1        |
dog  |true     |1   |0        |
dog  |         |1   |1        |
     |true     |2   |0        |
     |         |2   |1        |
     |         |7   |3        |
     |false    |1   |2        |
     |true     |6   |2        |
```